# Using flexbox on elements outside the html tag that are automatically inserted into the body

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm writing a little webapp and I'm using [kint](http://raveren.github.io/kint/) for debugging. It works grand.

I'm also using flexbox for my layout. It too works grand.

The problem is that if I use kint before any of my HTML is output it ends up "Above" the html/body tags.

The browser then places it *inside* the body tag which makes it affected by my flexbox properties.

As a result instead of appearing at the top of the page, it appears at the right and squishes my main over.

I want the debug divs to behave as if they're *inside* the `<main>`

My flexbox knowledge is rather limited (Floats ftw?) so here I am :)

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

nav {
    width: 150px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

main {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>Here is my KINT debug output</div>
<div>Here is more KINT debug output</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Edit user</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <main>Main stuff</main>
        <nav>Menu</nav>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is not a CSS issue, it's an issue with your debugging tool. Flexbox can't help here. You either need to change some settings in the tool or use javascript.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard... A full height nav down the left and the rest of the elements one after eachother. I presume it should start with `flex-flow: column wrap;` and a few `order:`

Comment: No you can't —flex box only work on siblings nested in a flex parent, so your debug messages will never be arranged in the same context (as if it is in `<main>`). You will have to move them somehow in there.

Comment: As  Paulie_D said you have to set your debugging tool to insert content  or append to  `main`. As for your layout you can try something like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/349/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the best solution would be do not set flex on the body itself

Add a div to be used as the container for all your page, and where the flex is set

```css
html {
    height: 100%;
}

.mybody {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row-reverse;
}

nav {
    width: 150px;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}

main {
    flex-grow: 1;
    padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div>Here is my KINT debug output</div>
<div>Here is more KINT debug output</div>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Edit user</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="mybody">
        <main>Main stuff</main>
        <nav>Menu</nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The strange thing is that the exact same CSS behaves differently depending on whether I'm flexboxing the body or the div inside it. With `flex-flow: column wrap;` it works fine on a div but move it to the body and suddenly the layout is completely different! Browser quirk or standard bug - either way this is my best option. Thanks.